# Mom-friendly digital camera with easy settings and batteries

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, battery

I am looking for a digital camera for my mom who is not so good with devices.

Using AA/AAA batteries is an absolute requirement, but the camera shouldn't be too bulky or heavy. The reason for this is only a fact that she wants to have a supply of extra batteries for longer trips far from civilization and any power sockets where you could recharge. In the city she would use rechargeable AA/AAAs.

She finds Canon's interface intuitive. We had a Canon PowerShot before, I think it was A610, and I find the settings "Sunny/Cloudy/Halogen/etc" and "Portrait/Nature/Sport" enough for producing good results and you also have space for experimenting. Automatic mode should also produce decent results.

Canon PowerShot sx160 is a good option, but it is very hard to find, did they stop producing it? I don't feel comfortable getting it because I feel like there might be some newer model and I'm missing out.

EDIT: SX170 was a typo, I meant SX160.
The most important part of the question is, is there anything with user interface similar to Canon's which does not require much skill with settings?

Comment: Battery reqirement? Why is that? Most everything has a Li-ion battery these days.  (Also, "me" is not to be used as a *subject* of a sentence": subjective/objective pronouns are tricky for non-native speakers.)

Comment: You said that AA/AAA batteries are a must, then you say you are trying to find the SX170.  The SX170, like all modern compacts, does not use AA/AAA batteries.

Comment: @thomasrutter. Not all. Nikon Coolpix L840, L32, and Fuji Finepix S9900W all run off AAs. But it seriously limits the pool of candidates.

Comment: Whoops I accidentally a word.  I think I meant to write "almost all" or "virtually all".

Comment: Canon A1400 is (was) an excellent point-and-shoot camera using two AA cells, 16 MPixel and optical viewfinder as well as LCD, which is problematic on *any* camera in bright sun. Sadly, they do not seem to be in production, and remainders are going for double the original price at Amazon.

Comment: Is the AA/AAA battery requirement related to the fact that your mom "is not so good with devices"? If so, you really need to reconsider this stipulation. Rechargeable batteries are easy to get used to, no matter how much of a technophobe the person is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get a list of cameras that use AA/AAA batteries is to use [the camera feature search tool on dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras#page=7), and under the physical features specify cameras that use AA or AAA batteries. The results will be listed in reverse chronological order (i.e., newest models will be at the top). However, the majority of digital cameras do not use standard batteries, so you will be limiting your choices quite a bit.

At the time of this posting (July 2015) [the Canon USA website still lists the SX170 as a current model](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/digital_cameras).